# I need help calculating the probability here for Final Fantasy 1

Tags: probability, probability-theory

So I am playing Final Fantasy 1, and I'm trying to find Warmech in the bridge leading up to Tiamat in Flying Fortress, however, trying to find him is getting pretty annoying. Anyways, I do not know how to actually calculate this, but given that Warmech has an encounter rate of 3/64 (rate stated by Steam). I ask,how many encounters do I need to fight before I have a 99% probability of encountering Warmech?

Thank you all

Comment: As stated, this is a bit vague. Assuming encounters are independent, the probability you seek is $3/64$.

Comment: A more reasonable question to ask is, how many encounters do I need to fight before I have a $99\%$ (or $95\%$, etc) probability of encountering Warmech?

Comment: Actually, that is better, let me revise the original post. Thank you very much.

Comment: $1-\left(\frac{61}{64}\right)^n\geq 0.99\implies n\geq 96$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have a geometric distribution $p_k = a^{k-1}b,$ where $a$ is probability of failure and $b$ probability of success and $p_k$ is the probability that the first success happens exactly at the $k$th attempt. In your case $a = 61/64$ and $b = 3/64.$ A question of related interest is "What is the probability that I will be successful by the $n$th attemp?" This is $\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{k = n} p_k = b \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n a^{k-1} = b\dfrac{1-a^n}{1-a} = 1 - a^n.$ You can now try to find the minimal $n$ such that this probability is at least $0.99.$ That is, the first $n$ such that $0.01 \geq a^n,$ or $n$ is the minimal integer at least $\dfrac{\log 0.01}{\log a}.$ With your numbers $n = 96.$